# IN Oracle SQL Developer can you pop-out query results/script output

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Was wondering if it was possible to pop-out the query results/script results window/s into separate "windows" windows, so for example I could have my query worksheet on one monitor and the output/results on another via an dual monitor set-up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But, you CAN take a query worksheet itself out of the main display and move it over to another monitor.

'Float' the worksheet - right click on the editor tab, 'float'.

Then you can minimize the editor bits of the worksheet so it's full screen results

that would look like this

[image]